# Transparency for Poly3DCollection plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, transparency, scatter-plot

I am trying to draw some objects with the fabulous Matplotlib package for Python. These objects consist of points implemented with `plt.scatter()` and patches implemented with `Poly3DCollection`. I would like to have the patches with a slight transparency so that the points and edges behind the patches can be seen.

Here the code and plot I already generated. Seems I am almost there, just missing the feature of transparency. Interestingly, if I first plot the `Ploy3DCollection` and afterwards the `scatter` points, the points can be seen, but not the edges.

Anyone having a suggestion for me?

[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = [0, 2, 1, 1]
y = [0, 0, 1, 0]
z = [0, 0, 0, 1]

vertices = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

tupleList = list(zip(x, y, z))

poly3d = [[tupleList[vertices[ix][iy]] for iy in range(len(vertices[0]))] for ix in range(len(vertices))]
ax.scatter(x,y,z)
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(poly3d, facecolors='w', linewidths=1, alpha=0.5))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I made a slight modification to the OP code and got the transparency working. It appears that the facecolors argument of Poly3DCollection overrides the transparency argument, so the solution was to set the color in a separate call to either `Poly3DCollection.set_color` or `Poly3DCollection.set_facecolor`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = [0, 2, 1, 1]
y = [0, 0, 1, 0]
z = [0, 0, 0, 1]

vertices = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

tupleList = zip(x, y, z)

poly3d = [[tupleList[vertices[ix][iy]] for iy in range(len(vertices[0]))] for ix in range(len(vertices))]
ax.scatter(x,y,z)
collection = Poly3DCollection(poly3d, linewidths=1, alpha=0.2)
face_color = [0.5, 0.5, 1] # alternative: matplotlib.colors.rgb2hex([0.5, 0.5, 1])
collection.set_facecolor(face_color)
ax.add_collection3d(collection)

plt.show()
```

Interestingly, if you explicitly set the edge color with `collection.set_edgecolor('k')`, the edges will also honor the transparency setting.

Answer (score 13):

I found a nice workaround: After plotting the data, do another plot on top with the same color and lighter line style. Instead of `Poly3DCollection` I use `Line3DCollection`, so no faces are plotted. The result looks very much as anticipated.

See below the new plot and the script creating it.

[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = [0, 2, 1, 1]
y = [0, 0, 1, 0]
z = [0, 0, 0, 1]

vertices = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

tupleList = list(zip(x, y, z))

poly3d = [[tupleList[vertices[ix][iy]] for iy in range(len(vertices[0]))] for ix in range(len(vertices))]
ax.scatter(x,y,z)
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(poly3d, facecolors='w', linewidths=1, alpha=0.5))
ax.add_collection3d(Line3DCollection(poly3d, colors='k', linewidths=0.2, linestyles=':'))

plt.show()
```

Comment: In general the patches for the `Line3DCollection` have to be closed (unlike as for the `Poly3DCollection`). In this example it does not matter, but generally we should end with a repetition of the first vertex, namely `vertices = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2]]`.

Comment: For posterity, `x`, `y`, and `z` are indices into `vertices`. It's a little confusing because they both happen to be small positive integers. The argument to `Poly3DCollection` is `[[v1, v2, v3], [v2, v3, v4], [v3, v4, v5]]` where `v1` is a tuple of x, y, z position values.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks a lot Chilichiller and Julian. Your examples are very useful to me at present, because I am working on a little project about 3D representation of matrices with matplotlib, and Poly3DCollection seems suitable for the task.

A little note, that maybe can be useful to future readers.
Running your examples in Python 3 gives TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable.

The simplest solution is to wrap the return value of zip in a call to list() (as indicated by "Dive Into Python 3": http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html).

Comment: Glad it was usefu l for you. I added now the list() command in the original snippet to make the sample code compatible with python3.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version that uses only one call to `Poly3DCollection`, where `edgecolors='k'` controls the color of the line and `facecolors='w'` controls the color of the faces.  Note how Matplotlib colors the edges behind the polygon in a lighter gray color.

[image]

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = [0, 2, 1, 1]
y = [0, 0, 1, 0]
z = [0, 0, 0, 1]

vertices = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

tupleList = list(zip(x, y, z))

poly3d = [[tupleList[vertices[ix][iy]] for iy in range(len(vertices[0]))] for ix in range(len(vertices))]
ax.scatter(x,y,z)
ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(poly3d, edgecolors='k', facecolors='w', linewidths=1, alpha=0.5))

plt.show()
```

**Caution** The API for `Poly3DCollection` is rather confusing: the accepted keyword arguments are all of `colors`, `edgecolor`, `edgecolors`, `facecolor`, and `facecolors` (using aliases and decorators to define multiple kwargs to mean the same thing, where the "s" is optional for `facecolor` and `edgecolor`).

Comment: It would be helpful if you can hyperlink the documentation of `colors`, 'edgecolor`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been fixed in the new matplotlib. I'm running version 1.5.1.

You can see your version by running python, then doing:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.__version__
```

You can get matplotlib using pip. If you're on Ubuntu, run this from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install matplotlib
```