# How to add or update the color of a 3D curve efficiently (without for-loop)?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, curve, colormap

Questions:

1. Is there a way to add color to a 3D curve plot more effectively than I am currently doing (e.g. avoiding the loop)?
2. Is there a way to update the color of a graph without plotting it all over again?
3. Is there a way to update one or more coordinate vectors without plotting it all over again?

Explanation:

I am making plots of 3D curves with color similar to the one in the example below. The number of points in my actual graphs is high, like `n > 10000`, which makes this approach very slow.

Also, the coordinates and colors are associated with the *fixed number of points*, which makes up the curves depend on another variable (i.e. time). Therefore I would like to plot the points once and then update one or all of the vectors (`x`, `y`, `z`, `c`) to speed up the plotting of each time step. 
EDIT: In Matlab you can do something like the following to update the coordinates of vertices/points already plotted. The example is with patches and not line segments, but the concept is the same:

```
v = [2 4; 2 8; 8 4; 5 0; 5 2; 8 0];
f = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
col = [0; 1];
figure
p = patch('Faces',f,'Vertices',v,'FaceVertexCData',col,'FaceColor','flat');
colorbar
pause(1)
v = [1 3; 1 9;9 1; 5 0; 5 2; 8 0];
p.Vertices = v; % this updates the point coordinates which I would like to do for the line segments in my python plot.  
drawnow
```

Code used:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100
x = np.arange(n)
y = np.arange(n)
z = np.arange(n)
colors = np.arange(n)/n

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
for i in range(1,len(x)-1):
    ax.plot(x[i-1:i+1], \
            y[i-1:i+1], \
            z[i-1:i+1], \
            c = plt.cm.jet(colors[i]))
plt.show()
```

EDIT: 
regarding my question 1: After gboffi's suggestion I looked into matplotlib.collections.LineCollection and can now plot the line segments much faster. I also used this answer [Matplotlib Line3DCollection for time-varying colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22078256/matplotlib-line3dcollection-for-time-varying-colors).

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Line3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
n = 100
x = np.arange(n)/n
y = np.arange(n)/n
z = np.arange(n)/n
colors = np.arange(n)/n
# "points" is used to restructere the coordinates array such that the first
# dimension is the point number and the third contains x, y and z of the point
points = np.array([x, y, z]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 3)
# "segs" is an array of lines between consecutive points in "points". So
# there is one line less than the number of points. The first dimension is
# the line number, second dimension is the start and end point, and the
# third dimension is the coordinates of the point.
segs = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
segment_color = cmap(colors)
ax.add_collection(Line3DCollection(segs, colors=segment_color))
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can use a [LineCollection](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection)

Comment: @gboffi that is a good solution to my first question. I have edited my question with some code on how I do it now with LineCollection. regarding the two other questions do you then know if the "segments" and "colors" are properties that I can access and set to different values so I just update the plot and do not need to make a new plot?

Comment: Playing inside the interpreter (I recommend this practice, possibly using the IPython shell) I can see that a `LineCollection` object has `set_color` and `set_segments` methods.  I'm not sure what to do next but [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.draw_artist`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.draw_artist.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-draw-artist) (that boils down to  `ax.draw_artist(my_lc)` ) seems promising.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** As suggested in [gboffi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872817/how-to-add-or-update-the-color-of-a-3d-curve-efficiently-without-for-loop/58874716#comment104017585_58872817), use a LineCollection. They're even faster than the below `scatter` approach.

---

If you can live without the line segments, you can batch plot all the data points using `scatter`, which allows different colors for each data point, and which is quite fast.

Here's a small demonstration:

```py
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100
x = np.arange(n)
y = np.arange(n)
z = np.arange(n)
colors = np.arange(n)/n

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
for i in range(1,len(x)-1):
    ax.plot(x[i-1:i+1], y[i-1:i+1], z[i-1:i+1], c=plt.cm.jet(colors[i]))
ax.set_xlim(0, n), ax.set_ylim(0, n), ax.set_zlim(0, n)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, s=1, c=colors, cmap='jet')
ax.set_xlim(0, n), ax.set_ylim(0, n), ax.set_zlim(0, n)

plt.show()
```

I did a small test with `n = 100`, and `n = 10000`, and also timed both runs:

[image: Output]

On the left side, there's your code plotting line segments, on the right side, there's the `scatter` version. It's up to you to decide, whether you need the line segments to visualize the desired effect you want to express with your plots. At least for `n = 10000`, I personally can hardly see a difference between both versions.

But, obvious is the computational time difference! You now can even afford to re-plot ALL data, when changing any of `x`, `y`, `z`, `c`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to suggest an answer to my question. I have used the LineCollection suggested by gboffi.

Comment: It's a good answer that solves the OP problem (although in a non-optimal way), has clean code, has benchmarks: +1

Answer (score 0):

I start from your last edit, with the required imports

```
In [1]: import numpy as np 
   ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
   ...: from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d 
   ...: from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Line3DCollection
```

Next, prepare the `LineCollection` — note that I have specified a colormap in the call and retained a handle to the data structure (different from your code)

```
In [2]: fig = plt.figure() 
   ...: ax = plt.axes(projection='3d') 
   ...: n = 100 
   ...: x = np.arange(n)/n 
   ...: y = np.arange(n)/n 
   ...: z = np.arange(n)/n 
   ...: colors = np.arange(n)/n 
   ...: points = np.array([x, y, z]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 3) 
   ...: segs = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1) 
   ...: lc = Line3DCollection(segs, cmap='plasma', linewidth=4) 
   ...: ax.add_collection(lc)                                                             
Out[2]: <mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3DCollection at 0x7f0528cdec10>
```

[image]

As you can see, we have not specified anything about the colors and our line came out in uniform blue.

Our instance of `LineCollection`, `lc`, has the property `array`, that is automatically mapped to colors using the colormap we specified (or `'viridis'`), so we use the appropriate setter to notify `lc` that we want to change `array` and eventually we notify the `ax` that we want to redraw `lc`.

```
In [3]: lc.set_array(colors) ; ax.draw_artist(lc)
```

[image]

Of course you can change the color-mapped array when you want, as long as you redraw `lc`.

Re changing the `x y z` data, you can change the segments using the appropriate setter, i.e., `lc.set_segments` but I'll leave that out of this answer.

Last, you can add a colorbar as in `plt.colorbar(lc)`                                                             `