# How to enforce transparency for pcolor slices within Axes3D scope?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, mplot3d

I would like to visualize 2D slices in a 3D plot by means of matplotlib and Axes3D, with some transparency to have a better view, as represented by

[image: picture depicting my data]

where the 2D slices clearly overlap. These slices are produced by `pcolor`, which in contrast to `pcolormesh`, returns a `matplotlib.collections.Collection` object and consequently can be handled by `add_collection3d`.

The issue of carrying the transparency property has already been discussed [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897786/transparency-for-poly3dcollection-plot-in-matplotlib) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23403293/3d-surface-not-transparent-inspite-of-setting-alpha), although the workarounds suggested (in Python comments below) haven't had any effect with my issue. My sample code is something along the lines of

```
import numpy             as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d   import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

alpha = 0.8

for i in range(len(islices)):
    im = ax.pcolor(X,Y,u[islices[i],:,:]) #,alpha=alpha)
    #im.set_facecolor((0, 0, 1, alpha))
    ax.add_collection3d(im,zs=xslices[i],zdir='y')

plt.show()
```